# Unable to structure a Firebase Database security rule properly

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my iOS app a user creates a username which has similar characteristics to a Twitter username. Once identified as being unique, it is persisted to the database with updateChildValues with the below signature: (username is JogBloggs in example).

```
     ["usernames/": ["joebloggs: \(user.uid)"]]
```

In my security rules in my fb database I want to create a rule that ensures the uid being uploaded is the same as the uid of the current user. how could I type a security rule to ensure this?  my attempt, below, doesn't work.

```
     "root.child('usernames').child(newData.val()).val() == auth.uid"
```

I have the following structure in my Database

[image]

With these rules associated with :

[image: Firebase Security structure]

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if I could then I would delete this question!! 
Answer is very complex and challenging.....

```
    newData.val() == auth.uid
```

Complete structure with correct answer below

```
    "usernames": {  
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.name == null", 
            "$username": {
                ".validate": "$username.length >= 1 && $username.length <= 15 &&
                          !root.child('usernames').child(newData.val().toLowerCase()).exists() &&
                                    newData.val() == auth.uid" 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great to hear that you found the answer. In future posts please don't post screenshots of text, but instead post the text itself. That makes it searchable and allows us to easily get your code/JSON to try and reproduce the issue or to use it in our answers.

Comment: Yeah sure, won't happen again and will change it. By the way, awesome video series on Udacity! :)